# JSON Unmarshaling

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring technologies and I am trying to develop a small web application servlet.

The app receives a JSON request, process it and returns a JSON response.

The JSON request Looks like this:

```
{ "Objects": ["Object 1", "Object 2", ... , "Object n"] }
```

I would like to unmarshal this request into the following simple POJO I wrote.

```
public class ObjectList {
   protected List<String> objects;
   ...
}
```

I have added the Jackson library, and I have a bean for the JSON view that looks like this:

```
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
    <property name="modelKey" value="obj" />
</bean>
```

Given the **`HttpServletRequest` request** that I have in hand, how do unmarshal it into the object?

Comment: Asked 3 years ago? Really?